# What is the best short message to get away from virtual meeting for short time?

Tags: sentence-choice, acronyms

Due to the pandemic, many daily standup meetings were converted into video calls but it is not always possible to be available on the call all the time, sometimes we have to get away from the call for a short period of time without leaving a call and it is always hard to explain
this each and every time. Is there anything standard sentence/acronym for that?

Comment: What would you do in your language?

Comment: Will you be able to understand hindi?

Comment: Try Hindi, if you can also provide a rough translation that would be great.

Comment: 'Abhi atta hun' rough translation 'I'll be back in no time'.

Comment: *"I'm just going for a pee break"* might be a bit too much information for many online business meeting contexts. So I suggest you just say *"Would you excuse me for a moment?"*

Comment: I think "I'll be back in no time" looks fine. You could include an "excuse me" or something else. Feel free to include a "self-answer".  I would upvote.

Answer (score 2):

A common way in more informal contexts to signify you'll return shortly is to use the acronym **BRB**: Be Right Back.

Another one is **AFK**: Away From Keyboard. This is often used when input is required or desired.

The first acronym emphasizes the shortness of the time of the user's absence, whereas the second lets others know the user cannot interact with the digital/virtual environment.

Comment: These could work in a gamer chat.  May not be appropriate in a business meeting.

Comment: @JamesK Fair point. I think these have already spread sufficiently outside of gaming context, but they might indeed not be suitable for (most) business meetings.

Comment: I see **AFK** as a status at work very regularly.